# Binning: Selection of Range (Cutoff) for a Variable

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistical-significance, supervised-learning, binning

In a current modeling work, we only use facilities with the secured portion % in the range of 70-100% (the range can be from 0-200%). These facilities (in the 70-100% secured percent range) are used for computing the average loss of facilities. Facilities with a secured portion not in the range of 70-100% are not considered.

We are interested in getting a range (can be other than 70-100%) using some statistical/quantitative method instead of the current 70-100% range, which is based on judgment.

Any general ideas/approaches on how to go around this? Even if you need some extra data/fields for this analysis, assume that you have it and just mention it in the answer.

**User2974951 Question:** Why/how did you select this range from 70 to 100 in the first place? What question did you ask to arrive at this answer?

**Answer:** Our data is segmented based on the primary collateral of the borrower (like Fixed Assets, Accounts Receivable, Residential Real Estate, etc). So a facility that has Fixed Asset as the primary collateral will be put in the Fixed Asset primary collateral group. Ideally, we should use only 100% secured facilities as they are not under-secured (<100%) or over-secured (>100%) but the number of facilities by primary collateral (with a count greater than 15) after a 100% filter is too low. So to have a good count of facilities by each primary collateral, we use 70-100% instead of only 100%. This is a loss given default exercise.

Comment: Why/how did you select this range from 70 to 100 in the first place? What question did you ask to arrive at this answer?

Comment: @user2974951 Basically our data is segmented based on the primary collateral of the borrower (like Fixed Assets, Accounts Receivable, Residential Real Estate, etc). Ideally, we should use only 100% secured facilities as they are not under-secured (<100%) or over-secured (>100%) but the number of facilities by primary collateral (with a count greater than 15) after a 100% filter is too low. So to have a good count of facilities by each primary collateral, we use 70-100% instead of only 100%. This is a loss given default exercise.

Comment: What is the purpose of binning? You can find many threads on this site arguing that in most cases it leads to information loss and is pointless.

Comment: @Tim Agree Business sense is that most of the facilities in the bank have less than 100% secured portion (not 100% protected by collateral). To have a conservative estimate we don't take these as they have a low loss if they default. With over-collateralization (more than 100% secured), we give them some extra recovery benefits. So we don't take facilities with 100% secured portion. The upper limit is fixed at 100%. I am interested in finding out how to arrive at a lower limit, which is currently;y 70%. This is more of a range selection with excluding everything outside the range

Comment: It still sounds like finding some kind of continuous score would make more sense here than packing things in bins.

Comment: @Tim Yes. I have very little power over methodology change. Senior developers have finalized this (and it is being used for years) and the only thing to be decided yet is the lower range of this interval. Can you provide some broad ideas on how to go ahead with this? Assume you have any data field you need (just mention it in the reply)